# Creating a scatter plot in visual basic with irregular x-axis values

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plot

I've written a program which reads measurements from an impedance analyzer as it sweeps over a range of frequencies or voltages, saves the data to a text file, and also creates a scatter plot. In one type of measurement, I  obtain x and y values for complex impedance, neither of which are the independent parameter. Now when plotting this graph, it appears that it simply puts each x value to the right of the previous one at regular spacings resulting in x axis labels looking like, from left to right, [45000, 43000, 40000,... etc.].

I've tried forcing the x-axis to start from zero which did not change anything and haven't been able to find much else on this. Is there a way to make sure the plot reflects the actual x values of each point?

Here's my current method of creating the chart,which pulls the data from the already created table:

```
For Each row In table.Rows  

       Chart1.Series("series1").Points.AddXY(row(0), row(1))

    Next
```